# How to generate documentation from Python files?

Tags: python, regex, parsing, documentation, python-re

How to create documentation from Python files without writing docstring?
I want to create a tree from all objects and classes and functions.
For example, this is my python file:

```
from core.server import handler
from core.ras import ras_main,ras
from core.lib.sort import SortedList,SortedDic
from core.lib.general import *
from core.lib.multi_strs import MultiStr
from core.ippool import ippool_main

class RasHandler(handler.Handler):
    def __init__(self):
       handler.Handler.__init__(self,"ras")
        self.registerHandlerMethod("addNewRas")
        self.registerHandlerMethod("getRasInfo")
        self.registerHandlerMethod("getActiveRasIPs")
        self.registerHandlerMethod("getRasDescriptions")
        self.registerHandlerMethod("getInActiveRases")
        self.registerHandlerMethod("getRasTypes")
        self.registerHandlerMethod("getRasAttributes")
        self.registerHandlerMethod("getRasPorts")
        self.registerHandlerMethod("updateRasInfo")
        self.registerHandlerMethod("updateAttributes")
        self.registerHandlerMethod("resetAttributes")
        self.registerHandlerMethod("getPortTypes")
        self.registerHandlerMethod("addPort")
        self.registerHandlerMethod("delPort")
        self.registerHandlerMethod("updatePort")
        self.registerHandlerMethod("deActiveRas")
        self.registerHandlerMethod("deleteRas")
        self.registerHandlerMethod("reActiveRas")
        self.registerHandlerMethod("getRasPortInfo")
        self.registerHandlerMethod("getRasIPpools")
        self.registerHandlerMethod("addIPpoolToRas")
        self.registerHandlerMethod("delIPpoolFromRas")

    def addNewRas(self,request):
        request.needAuthType(request.ADMIN)
        creator_obj=request.getAuthNameObj()
        creator_obj.canDo("CHANGE RAS")
        request.checkArgs("ras_ip","ras_type","radius_secret","ras_description","comment")

        ras_id=ras_main.getActionManager().addNewRas(request["ras_ip"].strip(),
                                                     request["ras_description"].strip(),
                                                     request["ras_type"],
                                                     request["radius_secret"],
                                                     request["comment"],
                                                     creator_obj.getAdminID(),
                                                     creator_obj.getISPID(),
                                                     request.getRemoteAddr()
                                                     )
        return ras_id

    def getRasInfo(self,request):
        request.needAuthType(request.ADMIN)
        requester_obj=request.getAuthNameObj()
        requester_obj.canDo("GET RAS INFORMATION")
        request.checkArgs("ras_ip")

        requester_obj.checkAccessToRasByIP(request["ras_ip"])
        ras_obj=ras_main.getLoader().getRasByIP(request["ras_ip"])
        return ras_obj.getInfo()

    def getActiveRasIPs(self,request):
        request.needAuthType(request.ADMIN)
        creator_obj=request.getAuthNameObj()

        if request.has_key("type_filter"):
            types = request.fixList("type_filter")
            def typeFilter(ras_obj):
                if ras_obj.getType() in types:
                    return ras_obj.getRasIP()

                return None

            ras_ips = filter(None, ras_main.getLoader().runOnAllRases(typeFilter))
        else:
            ras_ips = ras_main.getLoader().getAllRasIPs()

        ras_ips = filter(creator_obj.hasAccessToRasByIP, ras_ips)

        sorted=SortedList(ras_ips)
        sorted.sort(False)
        return sorted.getList()


    def getRasDescriptions(self,request):
        """
            return list of tuples in format [(ras_description,ras_ip)]

        """
        request.needAuthType(request.ADMIN)
        requester_obj=request.getAuthNameObj()
        desc_to_ip_map = ras_main.getLoader().getRasDescToIPMap()

        for ras_desc, ras_ip in desc_to_ip_map.items():
            if not requester_obj.hasAccessToRasByIP(ras_ip):
                del(desc_to_ip_map[ras_desc])

        sorted=SortedDic(desc_to_ip_map)
        sorted.sortByKey(False)
        return sorted.getList()

    def getInActiveRases(self,request):
        request.needAuthType(request.ADMIN)
        creator_obj=request.getAuthNameObj()
        creator_obj.canDo("LIST RAS")
        return ras_main.getActionManager().getInActiveRases()

    def getRasTypes(self,request):
        """
            return a list of all available ras types
        """
        request.needAuthType(request.ADMIN)
        creator_obj=request.getAuthNameObj()
        creator_obj.canDo("GET RAS INFORMATION")
        type_list=ras_main.getFactory().getAllTypes()
        sorted = SortedList(type_list)
        sorted.sort(False)
        return sorted.getList()

    def getRasAttributes(self,request):
        request.needAuthType(request.ADMIN)
        request.checkArgs("ras_ip")

        requester_obj=request.getAuthNameObj()
        requester_obj.canDo("GET RAS INFORMATION")
        requester_obj.checkAccessToRasByIP(request["ras_ip"])

        return ras_main.getLoader().getRasByIP(request["ras_ip"]).getAllAttributes()
```

For example, I want that information for my result, such as How many functions, class do we have? And the relationship between functions and class.
I won't use `help()` and `dir()` method, because I haven't any dependency modules.
I think it should be the use of parse Python file by `re` module and use of regex.

Comment: What sort of documentation do you want to generate? Python has ways of using the docstrings in functions and classes to generate docs, but you specified "without docstring and any comment", so it's hard to understand exactly what you want. Could you give an example of a kind of documentation generated?

Comment: the best place to keep information about a function, class is docString so I personally don't think that would be a good idea to generate doc without docString, since the help should also be first hand available to the programmer not just for the learner or user of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you don't write the docstrings nor the comments, you can still type:

```
help(your_object)
```

to get the automatically generated documentation of the class. 
your_object can be any kind of object, that is:

- a class
- a class instance
- a function
- a module
- etc.

So if you want the documentation for a given file (I understand a module), you can do:

```
import your_module
help(your_dodule)
```

if your file is called your_file.py and contains a class called your_class, you can do:

```
python -i your_file.py
help(your_class)
```

You can even generate the documentation from the shell prompt (not from the python interpreter prompt). Assuming again that you want to generate documentation for your_file.py, do the following:

```
pydoc your_file
```

Finally, if you want to generate html documentation for this module, do:

```
pydoc -w your_file
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But I don't see the file such as module.I see such as text file(.py), and I haven't any dependency of this file, and I can't do import it.

Comment: I just edited my answer, tell me if it helps. btw you should probably delete your own answer to your question, because this "answer" just adds more information to your question, and does not answer it. if you want to give more information you should edit your question insted.

Comment: another edit, showing how to use pydoc. I think that's what you want :-)

Comment: I can't import this file! because I haven't modules in this file!
how to create doc of this file without import?

Comment: your last comment cannot help me understand what's the problem on your side. I proposed you to do: pydoc your_file from the shell. If you tried that and it didn't work, you should give us a full log of the error message you got.